# Zebra Designer 3 for developers - multiple different design labels from one xml

Tags: xml, label, zebra-printers, zpl

I am using the zebraDesigner 3 for developers, and how we usually design labels is by merging an xml containing all variables with the .zpl created from the .nlbl, based on those variables, and send it automatically to the printer. But that is usually with just one design label per document (.nlbl), not multiple designs.

Does anyone know how to set up the .nlbl and the xml so that I can print multiple labels with different designs with one xml? Is this at all possible?